# WebSocket Stomp over SockJS - http custom headers

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs, stompjs

I'm using stomp.js over SockJS in my javascript client. 
I'm connecting to websocket using

```
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
```

stomp over sockJS connection has 2 http requests:

1. request to /info
2. http upgrade request

the client sends all cookies. I would like to also send custom headers (e.g. XSRF header) but didn't find a way to do that. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to pass custom HTTP headers to the WebSocket handshake requests.

Comment: It's possible, but i don't know how to do it with stomp client.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I'm experiencing a similar problem and I'd like to hear your solution, if you have one.

Answer (score 9):

@Rohitdev
So basically you can't send any *HTTP* headers using stompClient, because STOMP is layer over websockets, and only when websockets handshake happen we have possibility to send custom headers.
So only SockJS can send this headers, but for some reasons don't do this: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/196

Comment: Using cookies for authorisation in this scenario will result in granting full access to SockJS communication with your website from any website. This is a classic CSRF attack. (c) https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node#authorisation

Answer (score 9):

Custom headers:

```
stompClient.connect({token: "ABC123"}, function(frame) { ... code ...});
```

Without Custom headers:

```
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) { ... code ...});
```

In Javascript, you can extract an STOMP header using:

```
  username = frame.headers['user-name'];
```

In the server side, if you are using Spring Framework you can implementa an Interceptor to copy the HTTP parmeters to WebSockets STOMP headers.

```
public class HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor_personalised implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {


        // Set ip attribute to WebSocket session
        attributes.put("ip", request.getRemoteAddress());

        // ============================================= CODIGO PERSONAL
        ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = servletRequest.getServletRequest();
//        httpServletRequest.getCookies();
//        httpServletRequest.getParameter("inquiryId");
//        httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser();

         String token = httpServletRequest.getParameter("token");


      ...
    }
}
```

And for send messages without STOMP parameters:

```
function sendMessage() {
     var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
     var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            stompClient.send("/app/chatchannel", {},
               JSON.stringify({'from':from, 'text':text}));
}
```

and here you are passing parameters into the STOMP headers.

```
function sendMessage() {
     var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
     var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            stompClient.send("/app/chatchannel", {'token':'AA123'},
               JSON.stringify({'from':from, 'text':text}));
}
```

Comment: first of all it does not work in spring part. second: see @IRus answer for why

Comment: But I can send parameters with SockJs, is workig with my implementation.

Comment: I don't see the header no matter how many times I cast the ServerHttpRequest

Comment: I confirm, the spring part does not work, there is no "token" parameter available

Comment: so 'custom headers' seem to be not headers at all but request parameters judging by your processing of them? where did you get that code?

Answer (score 2):

SockJS JavaScript client does not support sending authorization header with a SockJS request.

Spring Java’s STOMP client allows to set headers for the handshake:

```
WebSocketHttpHeaders handshakeHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
handshakeHeaders.add(principalRequestHeader, principalRequestValue);
```

Additional information: https://www.toptal.com/java/stomp-spring-boot-websocket

And you can find a lot of infоrmation about this point on Spring documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-authentication

Short conclusion: for applications using cookies, integration is very good (Spring Security and other).

For applications using JWT, possible options are:

**1. Add as a request parameter and process in the implementation of DefaultHandshakeHandler**

```
var socket = new SockJS('/our-websocket?query=token_2222');
```

**2. OR add directly to the STOMP header of the message:**

**//add**

```
var headers = {
        login: 'mylogin',
        passcode: 'mypasscode',
        // additional header
        'client-id': 'my-client-id'
    };

    stompClient.connect(headers, function (frame) {}
```

**//Place of processing**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
                .setRelayHost("127.0.0.1")
                .setRelayPort(61613) //rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp ; docker exec -it ID bash
                .setClientLogin("guest")
                .setClientPasscode("guest")
                .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/registry") //позволяет отправлять сообщеня всем приватные сообщения всем юзерам
        ;
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");

    }


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/our-websocket")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new UserHandshakeHandler())
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {


            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {


                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
// 1) Perform authentication here using standard authentication providers (managers).

//2) Install the user in case of successful authentication or throw an error
                    accessor.setUser(new UserPrincipal("TEST USER 2"));
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Header(name = "token")` annotation inside the method if you are using Spring boot at the server.

Usage -

```
@Controller
public class SocketController {

    static final String token = "1234";

    @MessageMapping("/send")
    @SendTo("/receive/changes")
    public Object notify(MessageModel message, @Header(name = "token") String header)throws Exception {
        if(!header.equals(token)) {
            // return when headers do not match
            return("Unauthorized");
        }
        // return the model object with associated sent message
        return new MessageModel(message.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

You should have a `MessageModel` class with `message` variable and required `getters`, `setters` and `contructor`.

In frontend use Stomp

Usage -

```
function sendMessage() {
     var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            stompClient.send("/send/message", {'token':'1234'},
               JSON.stringify({'message':text}));
}
```

To add more security you an use CORS in Spring

Answer (score 0):

You must use query as parameter instead to use Authorization in Header.
(?query=token_2222)
example: var socket = new SockJS('/ws?query=token_2222');
then read it in HandshakeInterceptor as Sergio wrote